# What is the difference between calling a method from parent class using super() and using self?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, car_name, manufacturer, cost):
        self.__car_name=car_name
        self.__manufacturer=manufacturer
        self.__cost=cost

    def display_car_details(self):
        print(self.__car_name, self.__manufacturer, self.__cost)

class Super_Car(Car):
    def __init__(self, car_name, manufacturer, cost, 
                 top_speed, material_used, engine_type):
        super().__init__(car_name, manufacturer, cost)
        self.__top_speed=top_speed
        self.__material_used=material_used
        self.__engine_type=engine_type

    def display_super_car_details(self):
        self.display_car_details()  # this?
        super().display_car_details()  # or that?
        print(self.__top_speed, self.__material_used, 
              self.__engine_type)
```

Please tell me the difference between calling `display_car_details()` by using `self.…` and calling by `super().…`. The method which calls the above function is in `Super_car` class with name `display_super_car_details()`.

Comment: @Jonas:Yeah.Its working fine

Comment: This is not good Python OOP; if you're getting this from a tutorial, find a different one. There is no need for the `__name_mangling` attribute names, and your "display" methods should be named `__str__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case, there is no difference. If the methods had the *same name*, you would not be calling the parent class using `self.…`, but your own method again, creating infinite recursion.

With `super()`, the call is always going to the method in the parent class in [Method Resolution Order](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/), thus preventing the infinite recursion. More details on `super()` itself can also be found in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super).

Generally, you only need `super()` if you really need the inherited method, such as when re-implementing that exact method.

For example, running this code will lead to `RecursionError`, due to maximum recursion depth exceeded. The reason is that `Bar.method1()` calls *itself* over and over, because we are using `self.…` instead of `super().…`.

```
class Foo:
    def method1(self):
        print("I just want to be called")

class Bar(Foo):
    def method1(self):
        self.method1()  # oops

b = Bar()
b.method1()
```

This on the other hand has the intended effect:

```
class Foo:
    def method1(self):
        print("I just want to be called")

class Bar(Foo):
    def method1(self):
        super().method1()  # sweet

b = Bar()
b.method1()
```

Again, in your specific example it does not matter, because the other method (`display_car_details`) is *only* defined in the *parent class*, so it is unambiguous which method to call. If you had overridden `display_car_details` with something different, the use of `super()` and `self` would again yield different results:

```
class Bar(Foo):
   def method1(self):
       print("You are not supposed to call this")
   def method2(self):
       super().method1()
   def method3(self):
       self.method1()
```

Observe the difference in the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.method1()
You are not supposed to call this
>>> b.method2()
I just want to be called
>>> b.method3()
You are not supposed to call this
```

Comment: @SugaRaj Please reload and check my edits, I have edited my answer a lot in the last few minutes because I originally misread your question. Do my edits answer your comment?

Comment: I understood the edited explanation.But why does the language allow us to use either Self or Super() to call a method that is not in child class and only in parent class

Comment: @SugaRaj why wouldn't it? In this trivial case they both have the same behaviour; `super` becomes useful when you implement the same method name in multiple classes in your inheritance free (like you do with `__init__`).

Comment: @john So to my understanding, Its similar to python language allowing private variable to be accessed outside the class using  _<className>__variableName and using accessors also.Is it correct?